# How can I export code from the SeleniumIDE to eclipse and configure it to run as Java?

Tags: automated-testing

I've developed some automation in the seleniumIDE

How do I export that code to eclipse as java files and what other configuration will I need to do in order to run those files.

Comment: What do you mean by "export code from selenium to eclipse" ??

Comment: Made an attempt at guessing meaning and made the question answerable.  Original OP may be long gone.

Comment: accepted answer referenced seleniumIDE so I think that guess was ok (question didn't mention it until I edited it and added the reference you now see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy+Paste from [my blog](http://timothycope.com/?p=286):

**Problem – Selenium Popup**
You need to test an anchor whose target is _blank.

**Example**

- http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_TARGET_95y98y108y97y110y107y.html

**Solution in IDE**

- Open Firefox
- Click the Selenium icon to the right of the address bar
- Enter http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/ as your Base URL
- Click the record button
- Navigate to http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_TARGET_95y98y108y97y110y107y.html
- Left-click the a new window link
- Right-click on the page and select verifyTitle A Whole New Window – HTML Code Tutorial
- Close the new window/tab
- Right-click on the original window/tab page and select verifyTitle HTML _blank – HTML Code Tutorial
- In Selenium IDE, click the record button to stop recording
- Add a pause 1000 step after the click step to give the window/tab time to load
- Add a selectWindow A Whole New Window – HTML Code Tutorial step after the pause to connect to the new window/tab
- Add a close step after the verifyTitle A Whole New Window – HTML Code Tutorial step
- Add a selectWindow HTML _blank – HTML Code Tutorial step after the close step
- Select Play Current Test Case to verify the test

**Solution in Java**

- Export the test from the IDE solution (above)
- Click File -> Export Test Case As… and select Java/JUnit4/Webdriver
- Save as test01.java in your project’s src folder
- Refresh your project in Eclipse (F5)
- Fix any errors in the code and save
- Remove package com.example.tests;
- Open Test01.java
- Scroll down some and you will see some comments, like // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | A Whole New Window – HTML Code Tutorial | ]]
- Some of Selenium IDE’s functions don’t have WebDriver equivalents just yet
- Before the link click event add String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
- This will get the parent window handle
- After the link click event add for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);}
- This will switch us to the child window
- After the close event add driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
- This will switch us back to the parent window
- Right-click somewhere in the code file and select Run As -> JUnit Test
  Or, click the green run button on the Eclipse toolbar
- A browser window should open and run the test
- The test results should display on the left pane of the Eclipse window

Comment: This seems an answer to a different question?

Comment: Apparently the OP thinks otherwise. It does kind of answer the question, in a roundabout way.

Comment: Fair enough :).  I do think the answer would benefit by being made more concise to respond to the question.  So others who need the answer can find it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In my Selenium IDE version it is very easy to export:

1. Record testcase in Selenium IDE
2. Click File - Export Testcase As - Java / JUnit4 / WebDriver
3. Save File as .java

Your testcase is now java and can be opened and managed and run in eclipse.