# Driver lost focus

Tags: automated-testing, java, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I have one test case with java selenium webdriver. When I go to the login, everything is OK, but when I go to the other click in the new show, driver can´t find the object. Selenium IDE captured the target, but that is not working in the code and I get: `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I have tried with all types of by.

```
   public void bAdministracionUsuario() throws InterruptedException
    {   


            bAdministracionUsuario =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[3]/ul/li/a/span"));
            bAdministracionUsuario.click();

    }
```

Comment: could you add the HTML you are looking for.  Your method of selecting (specifically li[3]) may be causing your test to be brittle.  With the HTML it might be possible to make a better suggestion.

Comment: XPath is known to be the most brittle way to locate elements. Best practices recommend id > name > class > css > link text > xpath

Comment: NullPointerException is thrown when the application is trying to access an element whose reference equals to null. Can you provide the complete code for reference?

Comment: Please read [How to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) - a classic FAQ. Will help you immensely, and also help to understand the process (and critique) better. Good luck!

Comment: What do you mean by new show?

Answer (score 0):

If by 'new show' you mean new window, then you'll have to fill in the gap that Selenium IDE leaves when exporting to Java by using the [switch](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/) command.

I have an example in another SQA answer, [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/12066/11015).